# Pointers in structures in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using a structure named **avl_node** and the code is given below:

```
unsafe struct avl_node
    {
        Studentdb data;
        avl_node *left;
        avl_node *right;
        int height;
    };
```

I want to make a function **Height** in a class named **avl_methods**.. See the code below:

```
class avl_methods
{
    public unsafe int height(avl_node *a_node)
    {
        if(a_node==NULL)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return a_node->height;
        }
    }
}
```

The error which now I am getting is **Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type.** although I have allowed unsafe code in my project. Please help me. I really want to use pointers in structure as it is the requirement of my project. I am  developing a desktop app using WPF 4.0...

Hoping for a better response!

Comment: Could the problem be `Studentdb`?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? Pointers/unsafe code in c# is rarely required unless you are doing some p/invoke stuff (or performance critical code)

Comment: no, because studentdb is another structure which I am using in my code, and the error is due to the pointers.

Comment: post that structure 'studentdb'

Comment: As CharleH points out what are you trying to do? If you are just getting the height you don't need a pointer. If you are moving from C++ to C# (as I have done) it can take a bit of time to get away from pointers and "trust" C#. In your example you don't need pointers at all.

Comment: @Charleh , actually I have to make a student database using avl tree and hashing techniques as its the requirement of my semester project. I can easily make this on c++, but I have to include graphics too, and I am not comfortable while dealing with graphics in c++, thats why I wanted to implement it on c#, btw I can't use the built-in functions. I have to provide the whole functionality by my self!!! I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @ling.s  struct Studentdb
        {
            int student_id;
            String Student_name;
            Date dob;
            char gender;
            String department;

        };

Comment: Make `avl_node` a `class` rather than a `struct`, get rid of all pointers and `unsafe` keywords. It will work fine. You *really* don't need pointers for stuff like this.

Comment: @Belogix, I have to implement it using pointers and structures..

Comment: Why? The requirement is "make a student database using avl tree and hashing techniques". You can do that using normal safe reference types in C#, there should be no need to use unsafe pointers.

Comment: @ChristianHayter I have to use structures, its a requirement.... and for making the edges in avl-tree's node, I always use pointers....

Comment: @ChristianHayter I don't want to use "ref" keyword instead of pointers.

Comment: The two standard ways to implement such a data structure in C# are: 1) Use a reference type for the node and use references instead of pointers to refer to children. C# references are closer to C++ pointers than C++ references. They just don't support arithmetic, but you don't need that. 2) use a struct, put it in an array and use an index into the array instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
Studentdb
{
 int student_id;
 String Student_name;
 Date dob; char gender;
 String department;
};
```

Strings are reference types in .NET and are `non-blittable` for struct pointers.

Clearly, The `String` ans `char` in the `Studentdb` cause this problem. To understand why, you need to understand how the garbage collector works. It discovers garbage by tracking references to objects.

So the compiler can tell up front that the garbage collector will never be able to see the string references.

The only cure for this is to limit yourself strictly to value types. The only way to do that for strings is to allocate them in `unmanaged memory`

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx

Comment: where did you get the definition of the Studentdb struct from?

Comment: I am not getting the error for this, the error is due to pointers... If I comment-out the structure avl_node, then the program compiles perfectly!!!

Comment: This is the only cause to the problem, try without Studentdb data;

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be related with the Studentdb structure. I don't think it is visible from where you're declaring avl_node

This snippet raises the error you're getting

```
    unsafe struct avl_node
    {
        Studentdb data;
        avl_node* left;
        avl_node* right;
        int height;
    };

    //unsafe struct Studentdb
    //{
    //    int height;
    //};
```

This is OK

```
    unsafe struct avl_node
    {
        Studentdb data;
        avl_node* left;
        avl_node* right;
        int height;
    };

    unsafe struct Studentdb
    {
        int height;
    };
```

There is no problem with the declaration of the pointers in the code you posted.

**UPDATE**

This is the OP definition of the struct Studentdb, which I did not have when the user first posted

```
struct Studentdb
{
 int student_id;
 String Student_name;
 Date dob;
 char gender;
 String department;
};
```

You can also changed the struct you have to something like this:

```
    struct Studentdb
    {
        int student_id;
        char * []Student_name;
        char*[] dob;
        char gender;
        char*[] department;
    };
```

Since string is a clr type which cannot be used with pointers.

Comment: the data member "data" in avl_node has the datatype "Studentdb" which is also an structure... and I am not getting an error for that.... The error is because of the lines avl_node*left, avl_node*right...... There is absolutely no error because of Studentdb....